# unidentified object post from angularjs controller in expressjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

i have project of login page for admin redirect to dashboard. it use expressjs as a server side and angularjs as a client side.

this client side login page use angularjs

```
//this is the angular controller that use for get the data from login form
    (function () {
        'usestrict';
    "the initialize angular module"
        angular.module("myAdmin",[]).controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $http){
            $scope.login = function() {
                var userEmail = $scope.user.email;
                var userPassword = $scope.user.password;

                $http.post('/admin/',{useremail:userEmail, userpassword:userPassword});   
            }   
        })
    })();
```

this is the login page html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
  <head>
    <title>Awi Admin</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Aplikasi AWI Realtime Lelang Menggunakan Framework ExpressJS dan Realtime Database Firebase">
    <meta name="author" content="Muhammad Abubakar Siddiq - MAS Abbe">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/login.css'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css">>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myAdmin">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="profile">
          <button class="profile__avatar" id="btn_avatar">
            <img src="/images/avatar.png" alt="Avatar" />
          </button>
        <div class="profile__form">
          <div class="profile__fields">
          <h3 class="text-center">Welcome Admin Lelang</h3>
            <form name="login-form" role="form" ng-controller="loginCtrl" novalidate>
              <div class="fields">
                <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.email" required/>
                <span style="color:red" ng-show="login-form.email.$dirty && login-form.user.$invalid">
                  <span ng-show="login-form.email.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
                </span>
              </div>
              <div class="fields">
                <input type="password" class="input" required-pattern=.*\S.* placeholder="password" ng-model="user.password"/>
                <span style="color:red" ng-show="login-form.password.$dirty && login-form.user.$invalid">
                  <span ng-show="login-form.password.$error.required">Password is required.</span>
                </span>
              </div>
              <div class="alert alert-warning" ng-show="login-form.email.$error.email">
                <em class="fa fa-lg fa-warning">&nbsp;</em>Peringatan, username atau password salah
              </div>
              <div class="profile__footer">
                <center>
                  <button class="btn" id="btn-submit" ng-click="login()">LOG IN</button>
                </center>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('btn_avatar').addEventListener('click', 
        function () {
          [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.profile'),
          function(el) {
            el.classList.toggle('profile--open');
          });
        }
      );
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "/javascripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "/javascripts/bootstraps/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "/javascripts/login.js"></script>//==> this is the function for login that call the angular controller
  </body>
</html>
```

and this index.js as server side expressjs

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin     = require('firebase-admin');
    const express   = require('express');
    const engines   = require('consolidate');
    const path      = require('path');
    const session   = require('express-session');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    const app       = express();

    const firebaseApp   = admin.initializeApp(
        functions.config().admin
    );

    const HTTP_SERVER_ERROR = 500;

    app.engine('hbs', engines.handlebars);
    app.set('views', './views');
    app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

    app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing

    app.get('/admin/', (req, res)=>{
        res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');
        res.render('index')
    });
//this is the functions post for server side express
    app.post('/admin/', (req, res)=>{
        console.log('post login'+req.body.userEmail, req.body.userPassword);
        admin.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(req.body.userEmail, req.body.userPassword)
        .then(function (user) {
            res.render('/admin/home');
            console.log("success login admin".user.uid);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            res.send("fail");
            console.log("Error while executing firebase.auth() ",err);
        });
    });
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

this my project in github [project](https://github.com/MASabbe/awilelang)

my issue for this project is the data from the post function of angular controller to the expressjs post rendering detected as unidentified.
can anyone enlight me what is the cause?? and how to solved this.
this function is naver get to run firebase auth() functions

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are not debuggers. You need to isolate the problem and debug from there. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mcve], as providing a MCVE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as,

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '//admin/',
  data: {useremail:userEmail, userpassword:userPassword}
}).then(function(rsp){...});
```

Comment: did i need use this in the express ?

Comment: no this should be from angularjs

Comment: still have the same issue, unidentified :(

Comment: oh thats strange, can you check if there is any error on console

Comment: the console says 'Possibly unhandled rejection'. but the issue is why the express detect the data as unidentified

Comment: when console log in the client side definitly identify the data

Comment: oh can you just print console.log(req)

Comment: still have the same issue. unidentified

Answer (score 0):

this is the angular controller

```
(function () {
    'usestrict';
"the initialize angular module"
    angular.module("myAdmin",[]).controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $http){
        $scope.login = function() {
            var userEmail = $scope.user.email;
            var userPassword = $scope.user.password;
            var myObject = {useremail:userEmail, userpassword:userPassword}

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url   : '/admin/',
                data  : JSON.stringify(myObject)
            });   
        }   
    })
})();
```

this is the expressjs functions

```
   app.post('/admin/', (req, res)=>{
        console.log("####Success");
        console.log('post login '+req.body.useremail, req.body.userpassword);
        admin.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(req.body.useremail, req.body.userpassword)
        .then(function (user) {
            res.render('/admin/home');
            console.log("success login admin".user.uid);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            res.send("fail");
            console.log("Error while executing firebase.auth() ",err);
        });
    });
```

after remote desktop consult, final fixed